# Get values of cascading radio button values

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(amount)
{
  a=200;
  b=amount;
  c=a+b;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=a;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=b;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=c;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
```

I have 2 categories of radio button like

Names of cakes

```
 <input type="radio"  id= "c1" name="cake1" value="50.00" 
        onclick="if(this.value==50.00)  { myFunction(50.00); }">
 <input type="radio"  id= "c2" name="cake2" value="100.00">
```

-next is flower

```
<input  type="radio"  id= "f1" name="flow1" value="50.00">
<input  type="radio"  id= "f2" name="flow2" value="100.00">
```

Now the thing is I have a base price of 200.As soon as I select the first radio button `cake1` the price should increment to `250(200+50)`

Next if I select flowers column where the value is 100 the price should increment to `(250+100)=350`.
This should happen dynamically. Can someone please help me.

Comment: have your tried anything in javascript or jQuery?

Comment: @jogesh_pi, ya something like this <input type="radio"  id= "c1"name="cake" value="100.00" checked
      onclick="if(this.value==100.00)
       myFunction(100.00); " />

Comment: edit your question and update `myFunction(0.00)` function and its logic

Comment: @jogesh_pi, ya I tried like what I mentioned in comment..But did not work.Hence I did not update in question

Comment: You have to show us how your tried, we just help you to find the error on your code. No one here write code for you from scratch.

Comment: IDs have to be unique within an HTML document. Go fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intending that people should choose just one type of cake or both ?

The reason I ask is because once a radio button is selected, you can't then un-select it unless there is another radio button with the same Name attribute. You effectively have a list of radio buttons whcih can only be switched 'on' by the user.

If you want them to choose just one of several cakes, give all the Radio buttons the same Name attribute and the browser will allow only one to be selected.

If you want people to opt in one or more cake, then use checkboxes ( `<input type="checkbox" etc .. >`  ) so that they can un-tick them.

I think you'd be better off with a general function to reclaculate the whole page - eg below ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function recalculate() {
    var sValues ="";
    var fTotal=200; // base value
    var inp=document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (var i=0;i < inp.length; i++)
    {
        sValues +=inp[i].name+" = " + inp[i].value+"\n"
        if (inp[i].checked) {fTotal+=parseInt(inp[i].value)}
    }

// not displayed but at this point sValues holds a string of the input names and values.  just alert(sValues) to see it

    document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML= fTotal;
}
</script>
</head>


<body> 

<form name="form1">
cake1 £50 <input type="radio"  id= "c1" name="cake" value="50.00"  onclick="recalculate()" ><br>
cake 2 £100 <input type="radio"  id= "c2" name="cake" value="100.00"  onclick="recalculate()"><br>

flower 1 £50 <input  type="radio"  id= "f1" name="flow" value="50.00"  onclick="recalculate()"><br>
flower 2 £50 <input  type="radio"  id= "f2" name="flow"  value="100.00"  onclick="recalculate()"><br>

<hr>
Total: £<div id="Total">0</div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that yo wish to select a cake or a flower or both and then get the price for that based on: when you select a cake the total it's going to be its value plus 200, also if you select ONLY flower the total will be 100 plus its value and finally if you select both cake and flower (or flower or cake) we add both values plus 200(cake base) + 100 (flower base). if so, then I used this: file1.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

            function getTotal(){

                var data = "";
                var cake = $('[name="cake"]:checked').val();
                var flower = $('[name="flower"]:checked').val();

                if(cake !== undefined && flower === undefined){
                    data = "cake="+cake;

                }
                if(flower !== undefined && cake === undefined){
                    data = "flower="+flower;
                    ;
                }
                if(flower !== undefined && cake !== undefined){

                    data = "cake="+cake+"&flower="+flower;
                }


                //alert(data);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "getTotal.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function() {

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          $('#result').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });

            }

    </script>
<body>

<label for="c1">Cake1</label>
<input type="radio" id= "c1" class="cake" name="cake" value="50" onclick="getTotal();" />  
<label for="c2">Cake2</label>
<input type="radio" id= "c2" class="cake" name="cake" value="100" onclick="getTotal();" />
<label for="f1">Flower1</label>
<input type="radio" id= "f1" class="flower" name="flower" value="50" onclick="getTotal();" /> 
<label for="f2">Flower2</label>
<input type="radio" id= "f2" class="flower" name="flower" value="100" onclick="getTotal();" />

<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

getTotal.php:

```
<?php

$total1 = 0;
$total2 = 0;
$cakeBase= 200;
$flowerBase = 100;

if(isset($_GET["cake"])){
    $cake = $_GET["cake"];
    //echo "cake" .$cake;

    $total1 = $cakeBase + $cake;
}
if(isset($_GET["flower"])){
    $flower = $_GET["flower"];
    //echo "flower". $flower;

    $total2 = $flowerBase + $flower;
}

echo $total1 + $total2;

?>
```